# Get 'this' element from getElementsByClassName() function array

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I have this code:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('snap_img');

[].slice.call(elements).forEach(function(element) {
    var hammertime = new Hammer(element);
    hammertime.on('doubletap', function(event) {
        img_src = this.getAttribute('src');
        alert(img_src);
    });
});
```

I have an array at the top which contains all the elements with class name 'snap_img'. I need to get the 'src' attribute value of only the double tapped element itself (this). I'm using a variable 'img_src' with the value of 'this.getAttribute('src')', but no luck. It doesn't alert anything, the alert box doesn't appear now.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `element` instead of `this`

```
[].slice.call(elements).forEach(function(element) {
    var hammertime = new Hammer(element),
    img_src = element.getAttribute('src'); // now it works
    hammertime.on('doubletap', function(event) {
        alert(img_src);
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks like the right code, but the alert box doesn't appear at all. When I just do 'alert("hello")', the alert box appears. But in your code, you do 'alert(img_src)', which is the right thing to alert, but the alert box just doesn't appear at all. Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Thanks it works! I'll accept your answer in 4 minutes (regulations...) :)

Comment: @user3608176 you can do it now, I suppose ;)